# Сравнение строк в ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, коллекции, arraylist

Как правильно сравнивать строки в коллекциях?

Есть **задание**:

Сделать метод joinData транзакционным, т.е. если произошел сбой, то данные не должны быть изменены.

1. Считать с консоли 2 имени файла
2. Считать построчно данные из файлов. Из первого файла - в allLines, из второго - в forRemoveLines

В методе joinData:

3. Если список allLines содержит все строки из forRemoveLines, то удалить из списка allLines все строки, которые есть в forRemoveLines
4. Если список allLines НЕ содержит каких-либо строк, которые есть в forRemoveLines, то

   4.1. очистить allLines от данных

   4.2. выбросить исключение CorruptedDataException
   Метод joinData должен вызываться в main. Все исключения обработайте в методе main.

Создано 3 файла (1.txt [aaa bbb ccc ddd], 2.txt[aaa bbb ccc], 3.txt [eee fff ggg])

Мой код:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Solution {
public static List<String> allLines = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> forRemoveLines = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        new Solution().joinData();
    } catch (CorruptedDataException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void joinData () throws CorruptedDataException {

    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        File file1 = new File(br.readLine());
        File file2 = new File(br.readLine());

        BufferedReader fin1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
        BufferedReader fin2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));

        String line;

        while ((line = fin1.readLine()) != null){
            allLines.add(line);
        }
        while ((line = fin2.readLine()) != null){
            forRemoveLines.add(line);
        }

        //код для сравнения списков.
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(allLines);
    System.out.println(forRemoveLines);
    }
}

public class CorruptedDataException extends IOException {
}
```

**Ожидаемый результат:**

В первом случае в списке allLines остается только строка [ddd].
Во-втором все элементы списка allLines удаляются.

**Вывод на экран:**

> [ddd] [aaa bbb ccc]
>
> [] [eee fff ggg]

Comment: стоит добавить ожидаемый результат для приведенного примера

Comment: у вас неправильный вывод. В 1-м случае, если я правильно понял задание, `allLines` должны быть очищены, потому что `ddd` нет в `allLines`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за быстрый отзыв, буду стараться корректнее задавать вопросы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По заданию, если `allLines` содержит **ВСЕ** строки из `forRemoveLines`, то тогда из `allLines` удаляем строки, которые записаны в `forRemoveLines`.
В противном случае удаляем всё из `allLines`:

```
    ArrayList<String> allLines = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> forRemoveLines = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> delLines = new ArrayList<>(); //для проверки
    allLines.addAll(Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"));
    forRemoveLines.addAll(Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ddd"));

    for (String rem : forRemoveLines)
        delLines.add(rem); //копируем вторую коллекцию

    for (String rem : forRemoveLines) {
        if (allLines.contains(rem)) { //очищаем обе коллекции
            allLines.remove(rem);
            delLines.remove(rem);
        }
    }

    /* если коллекция не пуста - значит содержит элементы,
    которых нет в allLines, значит allLines очищаем. */
    if (!delLines.isEmpty())
        allLines.clear();
```

**Пример вывода:**

1) `allLines`: aaa, bbb, ccc; `forRemoveLines`: aaa, bbb, ddd. **Итог**: `allLines` удаляем.

2) `allLines`: aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee; `forRemoveLines`: aaa, bbb, ddd. **Итог**: `ccc, eee.

Comment: значит если файлы 1.txt и 2.txt будут на 100% идентичны то только тогда из allLines будут удаляться строки, а если есть хоть одно различие, то allLines удаляется полностью, в общем, в любом случае allLines должен остаться пустым?

Comment: @ImpulseProject во всех случаях удаляется allLines, кроме тех случаев, когда все строки из forRemoveLines содержатся в allLines (в allLines помимо этих строк могут быть и другие строки, естественно). Я обновил ответ, смотрите.

Comment: @Denis, да, вы правы. Судя по-всему, в задании требуется именно такое поведение.

Comment: @Arsenicum с 1-го раза я тоже не понял смысл задания, тем более, когда ТС показывал другой ожидаемый вывод.

Answer (score 4):

Я не уверен, что у вас корректно написано задание, но как я понял вам нужно что-то типа такого:

```
List<String> allLines = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")); // создаём и заполняем списки
List<String> forRemoveLines = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ddd"));

boolean isRemoved = false; // флаг показывающий был ли удалён элемент из allLines

for (String str : forRemoveLines) { // проходимся по списку forRemoveLines
    if (allLines.contains(str)) { // определяем содержится ли текущий элемент списка forRemoveLines в списке allLines
        allLines.remove(str); // если содержится удаляем его
        isRemoved = true; // ставим флаг
    }
}

if (!isRemoved) // если ни один элемент не был удалён, то очищаем allLines
    allLines.clear();
```

В результате, мы смотрим содержится ли элемент из списка forRemoveLines в списке allLines. Если содержится, то удаляем. Если же не было ни одного совпадения, то очищаем allLines.

Comment: как интерпретировать случай, когда в `forRemovelines`, например, 2 раза будет строка "bbb"? У вас неправильное решение - в вашем случае останется "ccc", а "ddd" нет в `allLines` => по заданию `allLines` будет очищен.

Comment: Arsenicum, понял логику вашего кода, но при любом исходе у меня удаляются все строки из allLines, могу выложить весь код, если поможет.

Comment: @Denis, во-первых, как указал, я не уверен, что автор указал корректное задание. А, во-вторых, я просто показал пример как можно сделать, а не решение за автора. Если ему нужно удалять все повторения, то, думаю, он сможет самостоятельно подредактировать код.

Comment: @ImpulseProject, у вас в вашем коде удаляются все строки? Да, выкладывайте.

Comment: Denis, по условию задачи, как я понял, нужно удалять только из списка allLines только те элементы которые содержаться (совпадают) в списке forRemoveLines.

Comment: @ImpulseProject у вас же четко в условии задания сказано - если список allLines содержит **ВСЕ** строки, то удаляем из allLines эти строки, которые содержатся в другой коллекции. В противном случае удаляем.

Comment: @Arsenicum обратите внимание на слово "все" в задании.

Comment: @Denis, да, я заметил. Поэтому я и написал про некорректное задание, и объяснил, что делает мой код.